# wp_posts data get deleted automatically in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress for my website. Dynamic pages are storing in wp_posts database table. After some days the data get removed automatically.

Is this due to any hacking or any bug in wordpress?

How to find the route cause for this issue ?

Comment: That's not normal. I would re-install WordPress, with the latest version. Make sure the site hasn't been hacked, too.

Answer (score 0):

You should reset admin password and database password and Try to update Authentication Unique key and salts from WP-config.php from word press API:

https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/

Change DB prefix by use word press plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/db-prefix-change/

If your website being hacked after apply above steps it should stop hacking and stop delete data from post table.